# Get AD Computers PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

how to get computers in AD with this `param`, can someone help me.

```
    Param(
        [string] $ComputerName = $env:computername,
        [int] $NumberOfDays = 10,
        [switch] $DebugInfo
    )
```

I tried but I cold not

Comment: You should really give more details. "I tried but I cold not"  doesnt really get us much details, what have you tried? how did it fail? did you get any errors?

Comment: The `param` block doesn't _do_ anything. You need to write some code _below_ it :)

Comment: I got this script on the net and I'm trying to get the uptime and downtime of AD computers, through the specific OU
EX:  $ComputerName = $env: 'DC=cor,DC=td,DC=teste,DC=com ' 

    Param(
            
     
       [string] $ComputerName = $env:'DC=cor,DC=td,DC=teste,DC=com ',
       [int] $NumberOfDays = 10,
       [switch] $DebugInfo
          
 )

Comment: `$env: 'DC=cor,DC=td,DC=teste,DC=com '` doesn't make sence.. It looks like you are trying to copy a param block from one script and combine that with some other script you found somewhere. Just try `Get-ADComputer` as command to see what it retrieves for you and from there think of what you want to do with that result

Answer (score 0):

Getting uptime with PowerShell doesn't scale well.. So please keep in mind this will take some time depending on the size of your AD.
If you need to query a specific set of computers (i.e. a specific OU) please use a LDAP filter. Example 4 in the following link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adcomputer?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Here is a basic script that gets lastbootuptime information for all the computers within your domain.

Also keep in mind that you need appropriate permissions on the target PC's.

```
#Get all relevant computers
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter *

#Declare an empty array to collect custom objects from the pipeline.
$ComputerInfoCollection = @()

#Iterate all computers an get uptime information
foreach($computer in $computers){


$UpTime = (Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $computer.name -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).LastBootUpTime
if(!$UpTime){

    $UpTime = 'NotResolved'
}


$ComputerInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{

    'Name' = $computer.Name
    'Uptime' = $UpTime

}

$ComputerInfoCollection += $ComputerInfo

}

$ComputerInfoCollection
```

Comment: No problem, cheers! Hope it helped or pushed you in the wright direction.